# How to get email notifications on the new Outlook Android app

Tags: notifications, outlook

The new Outlook Android app show new emails when they arrive but does not show the notifications for them. How can I turn on email notifications?
I am not using Quick Filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can set notifications to be for Focused only, all or none per
>   account. The default is Focused only, so if you turn off Focused Inbox
>   globally you get no notifications unless you go into the account
>   settings and set them to all. [[Ref. - Android Central]](http://forums.androidcentral.com/market-help/540140-no-notifications-new-outlook-app.html#post4525372)

In the new Outlook app, the default notifications setting is Focused only. In order to see notifications for all emails follow the following steps:

- Open the Outlook Android App `Settings`
- Select your account, e.g., john.doe@outlook.com
- Under `Mail Notifications` select `All` in the pull-down menu.

Comment: It doesn't work.